# Analyzing heap dump from OutOfMemoryError in Java

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, couchbase

my Java program is constantly getting `OutOfMemoryError`, and I believe there is a memory leak somewhere. While researching this issue, multiple sites suggested the Eclipse Memory Analyzer tool, so I added the `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` flag to the command, to get the heap dump the next time the error occurs. Upon checking the dump, the objects taking up the most space were "17,481 instances of "com.couchbase.client.core.deps.org.LatencyUtils.LatencyStats", loaded by "org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0x6c7c24510" occupy 1,978,652,856 (59.03%) bytes."  [image: 17,481 instances of "com.couchbase.client.core.deps.org.LatencyUtils.LatencyStats", loaded by "org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @ 0x6c7c24510" occupy 1,978,652,856 (59.03%) bytes.]

I thought this was the logger printing out too many logs, since the Java Couchbase code prints a LOT of logs on the `INFO` level, so I tried setting the log level to `WARN` but after trying it out, same result. Would appreciate any insight or suggestions, thank you.

---

EDIT: some parts of our code that calls Couchbase:

```
@Autowired
private CouchbaseConfig couchbaseConfig;

public List<ArLedger> getBranchArLedgers(String branchId, String fromDate, String toDate) {
        
    String query = Queries.GET_AR_LEDGER_BY_BRANCH_AND_DATE_RANGE;
    query = MessageFormat.format(query, branchId, fromDate, toDate);

    Cluster cluster = null;
        
    try {
        cluster = couchbaseConfig.connectToCouchbase();
        QueryResult queryResult = cluster.query(query);
    
        return queryResult.rowsAs(ArLedger.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Collections.emptyList();
    } finally {
        if (cluster != null) {
            cluster.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

And the connectToCouchbase() from the injected CouchbaseConfig:

```
@Value("${app.couchbase.connection-string}")
private String connectionString;

@Value("${app.couchbase.username}")
private String username;

@Value("${app.couchbase.password}")
private String password;

public Cluster connectToCouchbase() {
    return Cluster.connect(connectionString, username, password);
}
```

---

EDIT 2: Updated the code to follow dnault's suggestion, and a screenshot of the error that occurs when running the code:

CouchbaseConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Value("${app.couchbase.connection-string}")
    private String connectionString;

    @Value("${app.couchbase.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${app.couchbase.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public Cluster couchbaseCluster() {
        return Cluster.connect(connectionString, username, password);
    }
}
```

The repository code:

```
@Repository
public class ArLedgerRepository {
    
    @Autowired
    private Cluster couchbaseCluster;

    public List<ArLedger> getAllBranchArLedgers(String branchId, String fromDate, String toDate) {
        
        String query = Queries.GET_ALL_AR_LEDGERS_BY_BRANCH_AND_DATE_RANGE;
        query = MessageFormat.format(query, branchId, fromDate, toDate);
        try {
            
            QueryResult queryResult = couchbaseCluster.query(query);
    
            return queryResult.rowsAs(ArLedger.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Collections.emptyList();
        } finally {
            couchbaseCluster.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

And the screenshot of the error that occurs when the repository method is called:
[image: RequestCanceledException]

Comment: It looks like the Couchbase ClusterEnvironment is failing to stop the LoggingMeter it starts. Tracking as [JVMCBC-1077](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/JVMCBC-1077), targeting the Java SDK 3.3.0 release on April 5th. If you'd like to share the code you're using to create the `Cluster` during application startup and disconnect it when your app shuts down, we can verify this is the issue you're seeing.

Comment: Incidentally, this would indicate your application has called `Cluster.connect()` or `ClusterEnvironment.build()` 9,983 times over the lifetime of the JVM. It's general best to create a single Cluster and share it across your whole application.

Comment: @dnault Hello, thanks for replying! Yes you are right, the application does call Cluster.connect() for every query that it runs, which as I've learned just now is not the best way to go about it. I've updated the post to add some code from the application. Currently I'm refactoring the code to use only a single instance of the CouchbaseConfig class (I believe this is called a singleton?), do you think this'll fix the issue? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the update, and the details! The code you shared will still create a new cluster object each time you call `connectToCouchbase`. Instead of injecting the `CouchbaseConfig`, I would  make `connectToCouchbase` public, rename it `couchbaseCluster`, and annotate it with `@Bean`. This will give you a "couchbaseCluster" bean of type `Cluster` you can inject or autowire. (This assumes CouchbaseConfig is annotated with `@Configuration`)

Comment: Hello @dnault thanks again for the reply and the suggestion! I tried applying this to our code, and while there are no errors that show up before running, when I try running one of the methods that requires querying Couchbase, I keep getting com.couchbase.client.core.error.RequestCanceledException: QueryRequest, Reason: SHUTDOWN. I've updated the post with "EDIT 2" to show the updated code and a screenshot of the error. Thanks so much for the help so far!

Comment: @kei101895 that SHUTDOWN reason is usually raised when you're trying to use a Cluster that you've previously closed.

Answer (score 1):

@kei101895

There is already a couchbaseCluster bean defined in AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration.  If I'm not mistaken, that is the Cluster that @Autowired will use (I believe because it was needed previously by other @Beans and already created).

That couchbaseCluster uses the couchbaseClusterEnvironment bean which has a destroyMethod specified. This will ensure that shutdown() is called on the ClusterEnvironment

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public ClusterEnvironment couchbaseClusterEnvironment() {...
```

To customize the environment for the provided Cluster @Bean, one can @Override the configureEnvironment(builder) method in the couchbase config class.

If you really want/need to have your own Cluster bean, you can give it a name in @Bean("myBeanName") and then reference it with:

ApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
myCluster = (Cluster) ac.getBean("myBeanName");